# How to use dark mode in Bing Maps for WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, gis, bing-maps

In Bing Maps for Windows Phone 8, you can use dark mode in the Map control using the `Map.ColorMode` property. I have been attempting to do this in Windows Phone 7 with no luck. I have tried using:

```
        RoadMode rmd = new RoadMode();
        rmd.ModeBackground = ModeBackground.Dark;
        map.SetMode(rmd, false);
```

but the `RoadMode.ModeBackground` property is read only. Is there any other way to do this in Windows Phone 7?

'Dark Mode' might look something like what is seen in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14033/is-it-possible-to-access-the-bing-maps-dark-mode-in-the-arcgis-js-api)

Comment: Does it need to be set during the initialization? have you tried something like RoadMode(){ ModeBackground = ModeBackground.Dark }; ? Just a guess. I hate it when they make properties read only

Comment: It can't be set like that, still read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution that will work with Windows Phone 7 but require you to use the Nokia HERE Map imagery.

On Nokia Developer blog (http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Nokia_Maps_for_WP7_using_Bing_Map_Control ) you can find this post that shows how to integrate the HERE maps in Bing maps control in Windows Phone 7. There is also a working sample for it. You will need to request for a access key to use the maps, but that is free and easy. After you do that, you can change the day / night mode quite easily by changing the UriFormat property that is located in the NokiaMapsTile.cs file. The day API URI looks like this (that is the one already in the sample's NokiaMapsTile constructor):

```
UriFormat = @"http://maptile.maps.svc.ovi.com/maptiler/v2/maptile/newest/normal.day/{0}/{1}/{2}/256/png8?token={3}&app_id={4}&lg={5}";
```

As explained here on HERE website (pun intended ;-) ) – http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile , you have many choices for the `scheme` parameter there, including `normal.night`, so the URI will look like this:

```
UriFormat = @"http://maptile.maps.svc.ovi.com/maptiler/v2/maptile/newest/normal.night/{0}/{1}/{2}/256/png8?token={3}&app_id={4}&lg={5}";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm looking into it, will report back soon